# EASELJS - Does chrome not support the createjs.SpriteSheetUtils.addFlippedFrames(spriteSheet, bool, bool, bool) function?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-canvas, easeljs, createjs

I've been following a tutorial that uses this function.

And it does exactly what it's supposed to on Firefox but not Chrome.

If I comment out the line then the animation works fine but just obviously not flipping.

When the line is left in the code (aka. not commented out) Chrome doesn't display the animated image at all even if not using the newly created frames.

Is this a known thing? Or is there some sort of workaround/extra code that needs running? Obviously just creating the opposite images is a workaround but as I'm learning easelJS I'd like to know which browsers support which features.

Comment: Please give some code

Comment: I haven't heard of that before - but I've experienced animation misbehaviour with chrome due to caching. You could try clearing the cache manually and then try it again. Another issue could be that you are trying to build the sheet before the image was completed loading.

Comment: You can view the source here - just use inspect element:

Comment: http://david.blob.core.windows.net/easeljstutorials/easelJSSpritesTutorial03.html

Comment: Works fine for me in chrome

Comment: It only works once. Once it's in cache it doesnt seem to work... "Start" should also

Comment: Replay the animation without a page reload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't the addFlippedFrames function so I'm going to close this question and re-ask a new one thanks guys